# Hitting Play/Pause key (F8) ends FaceTime call

Tags: high-sierra, facetime

In High Sierra, hitting the Play/Pause (f8) button now ends a FaceTime call if one is in progress. This is quite frustrating as I often pause music after I answer a FaceTime call, is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Which application is playing the music when you hit the Play/Pause button?

Comment: Usually Spotify but it does the same for safari

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned in the comment that the music playing app is usually Spotify.

The media keys (Previous, Play/Pause, Next represented by F7, F8 and F9 keys respectively) gets associated with the an app outputting audio/video (if the app is programmed to support it).

If two or more apps are simultaneously outputting audio/video, the keypress is captured by Apple's own built in app (in this case FaceTime).

This explains your observation. In this case, it would be recommended to pause Spotify using it's menu command.

Comment: I understand why it is happening, I want it to not function in this way

Comment: I do not have Spotify installed. You give this [suggestion](https://superuser.com/a/107466/881716) a try.